# catch user activity within webbrowser or watin

Tags: c#, events, browser, watin

Is there any way to detect all the possible user activities within a ***WebBrowser*** and return a custom ***Event***? For example: User clicks on "search" button, return "SearchButtonClicked" custom ***Event***.

It would be something like, logging of all the activity that user does, stored in a sequence and could be automated once he wanted.

Edit: I do not own the webpage. I am trying to make an application to automate some searching on google.

Comment: Have you checked the mailing lists? http://watin.org/support/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I discovered the `HtmlElementEventHandler`.

Example:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("MainContent_LoginButton").Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(test);

// some code...

public void test(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked login button");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Wow, it's going to be quite a bandwidth intensive application... :) You might consider a framework like jQuery to attach events to all anchors and button-type inputs to perform AJAX calls to your server, for example. So you might have something along the lines of the following process:

Include a JS file on all your pages to do something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var trackUserActivity = function(elementId, elementText) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url/TrackUserActivity",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                ElementId: elementId,
                ElementText: elementText
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                // do something if call was successful
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // do something if an error occurred
            }
        });
    };
    $("a, input[type=\"button\"], input[type=\"submit\"]").click(function() {
        trackUserActivity($(this).attr("id"), $(this).text());
    });
});
```

Create a Web Method that can be called via AJAX to track the user activity:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void TrackUserActivity(string ElementId, string ElementText)
{
    // Implement your user activity tracking logic, like saving it in a database
}
```

After your OP edit, you don't own the application, so this won't work. I'm keeping the answer here for someone in the future who might have a similar need.

Comment: I edited my question. This solution may be very nice, but I'm not the owner of the webpage.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw so and added a "BIG IMPORTANT EDIT" to my answer... :P

Comment: Hey, you get all types on here... Some people are just too trigger-happy with that little down-arrow. :D Hope you find something that works for you though!

Answer (score 0):

See types of ***HtmlElementEventHandler***:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Use this event handler for knowing event occured. On event occured, get the element details, tag details and log in the file with the type of event.

See usage of downcasting required when using  ***HtmlElementEventHandler***
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsThisIsNotTheObjectYoureLookingwaitOhItIsTheObject.aspx.

When you want to replay action, you may run logged events in sequence, after extracting tag name and value fields.