# How to log user action in webbrowser

Tags: c#, browser

Have a web page with exam questions, and I need to record a user activity on this site.For example respond a answer when user need to click on a radio button but he can make many activities or change hers response many times. This online exam is for creating psychical portrait for examination.

For that I need an information, where user draw her mouse or how many response make for one question.

This information can't be on Video form or something else. The second problem is to emulate this record in real time - I supposed to save this information on XML.

And saved information emulation can't be do whit [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting my post from here:
[catch user activity within webbrowser or watin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908710/catch-user-activity-within-webbrowser-or-watin/21622240#21622240)

See types of ***HtmlElementEventHandler***:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Use this event handler for knowing event occured. On event occured, get the element details, tag details and log in the file with the type of event.

See usage of downcasting required when using  ***HtmlElementEventHandler***
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsThisIsNotTheObjectYoureLookingwaitOhItIsTheObject.aspx.

When you want to replay action, you may run logged events in sequence, after extracting tag name and value fields.